# Reversing GregorianCalender object's add minute method

Tags: java, datetime

When adding one minute to a `GregorianCalender` object, we do like below which adds 1 minute to the time:

```
GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
gc.add(Calendar.MINUTE,1);
```

But by mistake, I reversed it like:

```
GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
gc.add(1,Calendar.MINUTE);
```

Which added 12 years to the time. Can anyone please describe why this happened? My knowledge of Java is not good, so I am just curious why this happened.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure.

- The constant value of `Calendar.MINUTE` is 12
- The constant value of `Calendar.YEAR` is 1

So your second call is equivalent to:

```
gc.add(Calendar.YEAR, 12);
```

And this is why we try not to build APIs like this, of course. `java.util.Calendar` is a horrible API in any number of ways. Use [Joda Time](http://joda.org/joda-time) or `java.time` from Java 8 instead.